# combining shorthand and regression in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

sorry total noob question. I expect both javascript functions below to do the same: return sum of all the numbers equal and below the given number. 
Example1: input->3 output->6 (eg:3+2+1) Example2 input->5 output-> 15 (eg:5+4+3+2+1)

**foo works, bar throws a *SyntaxError: Unexpected token return* . why is this?**

```
function foo(num) { 
  if(num===0) {
    return 0
  } else {
    return num + foo(num-1)
  }

function bar(num) { 
  (num===0)? return 0 : return num + bar(num-1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) in front of the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) because a statement can not be part of an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions).

```
function bar(num) { 
    return num === 0
        ? 0
        : num + bar(num - 1);
}
```

An even shorter approach uses a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND).

```js
function bar(num) { 
    return num && num + bar(num - 1);
}

console.log(bar(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using expressions instead of statements -

```
const bar = num =>
  num === 0
    ? 0
    : num + bar(num - 1)
```